# Centering images inside inline <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a really simple method to center images inside of each `<li>` that I have for a simple carousel that I made.

It works fine on the initial page load, but then when I hit refresh the images start going haywire a bit and not centering anything (refer to images below)

***Here is my jQuery method:***

```
$ul.children('li').each(function(){
        var $pic = $(this).children('img');
        var height = $pic.height();
        $pic.css({ paddingBottom: (200 - height)/2 + 'px' });
});
```

***Initial load view:***

[image]

***Page refresh view:***

[image]

No idea why this is happening, I can only suspect that it is due to image caching. If you guys want to go to the live link take a look here http://www.metsales.com/metropolitansales/constantcontact/td/acrobat.aspx?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I loaded your site normally, then in another window and refreshed to reproduce the problem.  I inspected your CSS and it looks like the images that are too low have style="padding-bottom: 37px;", while the original ones that look normal have style="padding-bottom: 100px;".  Hope this helps

Comment: css issue! you need to fix the `padding` and `margin` on `li`

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa care to elaborate?

Comment: @Seano666 that's why I think it is an issue caused by caching. Just trying to figure out how to combat that.

Comment: As far as I know, you can append the img src with a random string to keep it from caching.  I suspect that is not the full problem though.   eg.  src="images/image.jpg?3453452"

Comment: **1**.img tag has margin-top: -100px; **2**.carousel li has
padding: 5px; in your case you dont need padding top and bottom you need to fix both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix

```
 $ul.children('li').each(function(){
    var $pic = $(this).children('img');
    var height = $pic.outerHeight();
    $pic.css({ marginTop: (200 - height)/2 + 'px' });//remove this line
 });
```

Because you need to remove `margin-top: -100px;` in img tag also add `vertical-align: middle;`

`carousel li` has `padding: 5px;` 
in your case you dont need padding top and bottom but it is a optional to give `hover` affect

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using `vertical-align: middle;` I have to really learn when it is applicable because it never works for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Recently i'm using translateY in this cases. It should be like this

```
li {
    width: xxx; // set the item width
    height: xxx; // set the item height
    position: relative;
}

img {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%); // This should make the image go in direction to the top using 50% of its height value
}
```

Tip: You should avoid that padding in the `<li>`.

See ya!

Comment: setting the images to `position: absolute;` messes up the whole carousel

Answer (score 0):

Your `li`s don't align properly. One thing you could do is make the `ul` really wide and float your `li`s in there. Add this to your css:

```
ul {
  width: 1000%;
}

li {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
```

And remove your js that sets the padding and margin and change it to:

```
 $ul.children('li').each(function(){
    var $pic = $(this).children('img');
    var height = $pic.outerHeight();
    $pic.css({ marginTop: (200 - height)/2 + 'px' });
 });
```